# Printf takes only the last scanf

Tags: c

I have this code here:

```
int main() {
char cognome[] = {};
char nome[] = {} ;
char sesso[] = {};
char giorno_n[] = {};
char mese_n[] = {};
char anno_n[] = {};
char comune[] = {};
char lettera[] = {};
int i;


printf("Programma che calcola il codice fiscale.\n");
printf("Inserisci il cognome: ");
scanf("%s", cognome);
strupr(cognome);
printf("Inserisci il nome: ");
scanf("%s", nome);
strupr(nome);
printf("Inserisci il sesso: ");
scanf("%s", sesso);
strupr(sesso);
printf("Inserisci il giorno di nascita: ");
scanf("%s", giorno_n);
printf("Inserisci il mese di nascita: ");
scanf("%s", mese_n);
printf("Inserisci l'anno di nascita: ");
scanf("%s", anno_n);
printf("Inserisci il comune di nascita: ");
scanf("%s", comune);
printf("Il comune è: %s", comune);

printf("%s", cognome);


getch();


}`
```

The problem with this code is that the last `printf("%s", cognome)` doesn't take the input value of the `scanf("%s", cognome)`, but it takes the value of the last `scanf("%s", comune)`, and I really don't understand why.

Comment: This is not C. All your iniitializations should not compile. `{}` is only allowed in C++, but generally the compiler tries to determine the size of incomplete arrays (those with `[]`) from the initializer.

Comment: I tried with just char name_of_string[]; but it didn't work, so I've put the {} in order to make it works.

Comment: No, it cannot be compiled perfectly. You should have got a lot of diagnostics. (Or you compiled it as C++?). Repair them first.

Comment: which compiler did you use? even if you fix to `char cognome[] = "";`, you didn't specify any space for the array so it won't work

Comment: Basically I'm using the gcc compiler. So the problem is that I have to specify the size of each array I declared?

Comment: Yes, or give it an initializer that has enough elements. Otherwise the compiler can't know what you need. But I didn't check if this are all your errors. If you still have some, please come back in a new question with a minimal example that compiles cleanly and that shows your problem. Also it would be nice if you could indent code that you are posting here.

Comment: BTW: not directly related to your problem: you probably don't want to read month, day and year as a string.

Comment: Your code [does not compile](https://ideone.com/pMu3xN#cmperr). You may be using a broken compiler, or a compiler for a different language, or a compiler with too lax default settings. No one knows until you share relevant details about your environment.

Comment: If you are using gcc, use compilation  flags -Wall -pedantic -Werror -std=c99 (or -std=c11 if you want to). They are an absolute must.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a maximum length for each of your strings.

For example:

```
char cognome[30];   // maximum lenght of cognome is 30-1 (1 for the NUL terminator)
char nome[30];      // etc.
```

And then call `scanf` like this:

```
scanf("%29s", cognome);
```

So you won't get a buffer overflow if the user enters a name longer than 29 chars.

Comment: Well, it seems that now it works. I didn't think I had to specify the length of each array because I thought the scanf automatically gave it to the array after writing it in input. Anyway, in order to answer about your BTW: actually I need them as strings, that's why they are of that type. Thanks again!

Comment: Learn also about using `%ms` in `scanf`, or to use [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)